# Gravity not working in unity RigidBody 2D transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I made sprite and applied rigidbody 2d component, it's working fine as it should, now i wrote this piece of code but, when i start playing the game it working for some period of time but after that, gravity seems be null, means my rigidbody does not come down when i leave the keys

`// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            posX--;
        } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            posX++;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            posY++;

        } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            posY--;
        }
            angle -= Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
            angle = Mathf.Clamp (angle, -10, 10);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0,0,angle);
        transform.position = new Vector2 (posX * Time.deltaTime, posY * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}`
what i want to do is move the helicopter left right up and down(which user can control) but when user is not interacting, i want gravity to work as default and helicopter will come down due to gravity, how to achieve that?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the position on every frame, so it doesn't meter what Unity calculates on its physics, you overwrite when you do this:

```
transform.position = new Vector2 (posX * Time.deltaTime, posY * Time.deltaTime);
```

I don't know what you want to achieve, but maybe it will work if after this you re-apply a gravity force with `traforme.AddForce()`, using the object's mass and the gravity acceleration constant.

Comment: see the improved version and tell me how to achieve it :)

Comment: I already told you, you are **overwriting** the position, the gravity will act in the position but you reset it when you assign a value to it. You can either simulate the gravity by applying a force after setting the position or simply don't set the position - you can apply a force up instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AddForce instead of Changing x and Y axes.
You can see the example here,

[AddFource Example](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)